# Why my browser transforms ISO-8859-15 special characters (Œ, œ, Ÿ) to (¼, ½, ¾)

Tags: java, html, browser, character-encoding

I have a text input in an HTML form, my page is configured to use ISO-8859-15

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-15">
```

When I type one of the following characters (Œ, œ, Ÿ) and submit the form, I can see in Firebug that it is transformed (¼, ½, ¾), I also see this when Debugging (Eclipse).
I can't understand why.

Wikipedia page : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-15

Comment: "my page is configured to use ISO-8859-15" — Why? This is the 21st century. ISO-8859 has been legacy for decades.

Comment: Legacy application, for decades

Comment: Firebug may simply be interpreting the data in the wrong charset? That doesn't necessarily indicate that the wrong data is being sent.

Comment: What does the HTTP header for this page say? The http-equiv meta tag does not override the data sent in the actual HTTP header.

Comment: HTTP header is : `Content-Type : text/html;charset=ISO-8859-15`

Comment: @deceze, +1, Firefox correctly uses ISO-8859-15 (see my answer). Firebug is simply not aware of this (as he can't without header in the emitted request).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apache Tomcat Wiki explains this problem pretty well.

> Most web browsers today do not specify the character set of a request, even when it is something other than ISO-8859-1. This seems to be in violation of the HTTP specification. Most web browsers appear to send a request body using the encoding of the page used to generate the POST

Consequently, you need to tell your application which encoding is used in incoming HTTP request.

You have to call the following function (prior to any parameter parsing) :

```
httpServletRequest.setCharacterEncoding("ISO-8859-15");
```

It seems that the best practice on this point, is to set a javax.servlet.Filter doing this. Spring comes with one doing it as we need :

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>webapp</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>
```